# Questions in wrong sort order?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Since about an hour or less the question under the c# tag come sorted oldest first.

Adding any other tag seems to work but the pure c# tag

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

reverts the sort order. Am I alone with this??

[image]

Comment: Looks like someone messed with an `ORDER BY`...

Comment: There is something else wrong as well for example in [mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)

Comment: someone messed with the tags too... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326191/error-while-showing-tagged-questions

Comment: python and iOS suffer from the same fate.

Comment: We had too many crap questions, so the staff decided to delete the posts from the past few years. Late spring cleaning!

Comment: July 09 seems to be the cut off point of the query. Subsequent pages seem to show only older question.

Comment: Some tag pages also seem to be returning results for the [wrong tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326191/error-while-showing-tagged-questions).

Comment: @Cerbrus and even being different problems they want to close my topic...

Comment: @Dot_Py: Different problem with (probably) the same cause.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] this - more as we are back to the old code paths than that the new code is fixed.

Comment: @Cerbrus I *wish* this was as simple as an `ORDER BY`; none of this is SQL...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That'll be me, dammit. We're looking at replacing some of our core code that does all the tag filtering (etc) - apparently there are still some glitches! I've switched back to v1 while we investigate.

Comment: 6-8 glitches, it looks like ;-)

Comment: We are happy to help you test, don't sweat over it ...

Comment: Thanks, it is working agian.. I was so baffled to see almost all answers already answered and accepted ;-)