# Error while showing tagged questions

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I mark `show only 'Python Tagged' questions`, the website is showing me only `'PHP Tagged' questions`.

I already cleared my cache and nothing.

The PHP Tagged questions and PHP RSS feed show only PHP Tagged questions.

What should I do?

[The python tagged questions RSS feed is bugged too](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=python&sort=newest)...

[image: Python tagged questions without Python questions]

Comment: @gunr2171 it's not a duplicate. they're different problems. question order <> question tag. please delete your flag.

Comment: @gunr2171 "the same root cause" - aka "me"; definitely a different thing, though - I suspect this relates to "and" vs "or" (as the default) - will investigate

Comment: @gunr2171 `probably the same cause` means you don't know if it's the exact cause or not. please read the whole topic before asking to close topics.

Comment: @Dot_Py: As answered in the dupe target, this issue was caused by the same change as the issue in the dupe target.

Comment: @Cerbrus as the dev responsible: from my perspective they are different bugs, and I'm very happy for them to be logged separately