# jhipster tag search broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

It just happened one hour ago. Tag search for [jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jhipster) got broken and now returns unrelated questions which seem to be tagged for [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

Comment: I can't reproduce it, for me it yields normal results ...

Comment: I definitely repro'ed this after seeing the question. I suspected someone had done something stupid, like created a tag synonym. Good to see that wasn't the case. Marc is probably [still working on it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326193/366904).

Comment: I checked the tag synonyms for jhipster there were none at the time of the incident

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is working normally now, I should have taken a screenshot. Thanks

Comment: I saw it; thanks for reporting; something definitely not happy, but I've disabled the affected code now